# URL Redirection using Auth0's state parameter in OWIN doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, auth0

We're currently on the free version of Auth0 and we created a new project (started with [this](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnet-owin-mvc-samples/tree/master/Quickstart/00-Starter-Seed/MvcApplication)) for Auth0 for OWIN (ASP.NET) but no matter what we pass for a redirect url, we always get redirected to the root of the application after successful login.

I even looked at the `Auth0.Owin` source ([here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin)) and it appears that the `authorize` request is built correctly and looks something like:

> https://myapp.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=dasojd09asudaosidj&connection=&response_type=code&state=**6UwOVen2DDCHH3WgPEQ2BisyiIt9UehGo3NNtkDoxBAj3Oexyz17viCvwrkleBA7OoNw4ZdxmNCIXKk9p2sYwVFrhbzjp623Y_EDicq3biEi_AYqkKoNAltmSFyjpM6z**&scope=openid%20profile

but after that goes up and comes back from auth0.com the `login` looks like (note that the `state` is different):

> https://myapp.auth0.com/login?state=**woSo7Y2CxjSPvKeG6al8b_OrzHFB88-P**&client=dasojd09asudaosidj&protocol=oauth2&connection=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53474%2Fsignin-auth0&scope=openid%20profile&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.auth0.com%2Fuserinfo

and when I inspect the decoded `state`, it just literally has the characters `hereisthestate` even though it originally had something like `http://localhost:53474?query=99999`.

I am trying to follow the guidelines spelled out in the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state) but it just appears that auth0.com is mucking up the `state` parameter when it gets it from the `login` call.

Am I missing a flag or setting? Shouldn't the `state` remain the same through the lifecycle? Is this because we are on the free tier?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue here was due to the configuration of our application on the Hosted Pages. The Login has been altered to the following:

```
params: {state: "hereisthestate", scope:"openid email"}
```

We changed it to the default:

```
params: config.internalOptions
```

and now our application redirects as desired!